# XSLT: XML: Replace Function/Functionality

Tags: xml, xslt

I would like to product the following html

```
words<block>words</block>
```

From this node in an xml doc

```
<text>words bli!wordsbli!</text>
```

the bli! represents a tag that will occur in random spots with in the  node of the xml doc.  Is it possible to replace the bli! with  using an xslt function?

Comment: Do you want to replace ` bli!` or `<block>`?

Comment: It's easy using XSLT 2.0 and regular expressions. It's more difficult using 1.0. Which version are you using?

Comment: @Michael Seal version2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing built into XSLT 1.0 that will do basic string replacement.

[This post](http://geekswithblogs.net/Erik/archive/2008/04/01/120915.aspx) goes over a good method for implementing this functionality.

```
 <xsl:template name="string-replace-all">
    <xsl:param name="text" />
    <xsl:param name="replace" />
    <xsl:param name="by" />
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="contains($text, $replace)">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text,$replace)" />
        <xsl:value-of select="$by" />
        <xsl:call-template name="string-replace-all">
          <xsl:with-param name="text"
          select="substring-after($text,$replace)" />
          <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="$replace" />
          <xsl:with-param name="by" select="$by" />
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="$text" />
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
```

Here's how it is called:

```
  <xsl:variable name="myVar">
    <xsl:call-template name="string-replace-all">
      <xsl:with-param name="text" select="'This is a sample text : {ReplaceMe} and {ReplaceMe}'" />
      <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="'{ReplaceMe}'" />
      <xsl:with-param name="by" select="'String.Replace() in XSLT'" />
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:variable>
```